# How do I change the default format of log messages in python app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, python-logging

I would like to log the module and classname by default in log messages from my request handlers.

The usual way to do this seems to be to set a custom format string by calling `logging.basicConfig`, but this can only be called once and has already been called by the time my code runs.

Another method is to create a new log `Handler` which can be passed a new log `Formatter`, but this doesn't seem right as I want to use the existing log handler that App Engine has installed.

What is the right way to have extra information added to all log messages in python App Engine, but otherwise use the existing log format and sink?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I cooked this up by reading the `logging` module's `__init__.py`. I don't know if this is proper, but it seems to work:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    )

logging.info('Danger Will Robinson!')
# 03-31 20:00 root         INFO     Danger Will Robinson!
root = logging.getLogger()
hdlr = root.handlers[0]
fmt = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
logging.info('Danger Will Robinson!')
# root        : INFO     Danger Will Robinson!
```

Comment: I noticed, that `root.handlers[0]` doesn't work, if `basicConfig()` was NOT called before. Why is that?

Comment: `logging.basicConfig` is a convenience function which sets up a root handler. If you don't define a handler then `root.handlers` is an empty list. So trying to access the first element of an empty list, e.g. `root.handlers[0]`, raises an `IndexError`. Whenever you use the `logging` module you must either call `logging.basicConfig` or read a config from a file (e.g. `logging.config.fileConfig`) or [set up the handler(s) yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139462/190597).

Answer (score 6):

I found this to be working for Python 3.6, it will set the logging level / format for all subsequent logging calls, even if `logging` is called by previous imports.

```
logging_level = logging.INFO
logging_fmt = "%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"   # the default
try:
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()
    root_logger.setLevel(logging_level)
    root_handler = root_logger.handlers[0]
    root_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(logging_fmt))
except IndexError:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging_level, format=logging_fmt)
```

Comment: Is this the most compact / elegant it can get with current versions of python 3?

Comment: @matanster unfortunately I am not expert enough to answer that, perhaps others can comment on this

Comment: @matanster as of Python 3.2, logger objects have `hasHandler()` method. This can help to get rid of the try - except.