# Python logging not outputing correct levels?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to add some logging to my application however I can't seem to get the correct log level statements to display. I have set my logger to `INFO` yet it only displays `warnings` and `errors` in both the console and log file

Am I missing anything?

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("mo_test")
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

fh = logging.FileHandler('test.log')
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
fh.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(ch)

logger.info("This is an Info")
logger.debug("this is a debug")
logger.warning("This is a warning")
logger.error("Oh error")
```

The content of the log file and console is then only:

```
2015-03-09 15:32:44,601 - mo_test - WARNING - This is a warning
2015-03-09 15:32:44,601 - mo_test - ERROR - Oh error
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the logging level on the logger. If you don't set it, the default logging level is 30, i.e. `logging.WARNING`:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("mo_test")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

[The logging flow chart](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow) shows how the logger itself filters by logging level (*"Logger enabled for level of call?"*) even before the handlers get a chance to handle the record (*"Handler enabled for level of LogRecord?"*):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a call to ``logging.basicConfig()`. Without this call,`logging` is in an unconfigured state and anything can happen.

Comment: Vinay Sajip, maintainer/developer of the logging module, [shows `basicConfig` is just a convenience function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4139462/190597). You are free to set up logging without it.