# How to set default app to open log-files despite changing file endings (in MobaXterm)?

Tags: python, windows, logging, ssh, pbs

> Is there a way to set the default application for those log files even
>   if the file endings are constantly changing?

I am working on MobaXterm, and after running some code through a *.pbs file I get the error and output log files in the form:

```
sample_code.o23456
sample_code.e23456
```

When I am opening the log files I am asked to set a default app and to choose an app to open the log files.

The next time I execute it the file endings will have changed

```
sample_code.o23457
sample_code.e23457
```

Which will leave me again with selecting the app to open the log files.

This is time consuming.

Is there a way to set the default application for those log files even if the file endings are constantly changing?

*Note*: I am coding in python if that helps and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557168/how-do-i-change-the-default-format-of-log-messages-in-python-app-engine) but I don't really want to mess with the log handler.

*Edit*: Okay [this](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#3_1_2) is what I found out so far. One can set the default editor, but this is not solving my problem with the changing file endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer lies within the *.pbs file

You can rename the pbs directive by adding following lines for the output and error logs to the *.pbs script, choosing names and file endings that suit your purpose (in my case just having the same endings every time to choose a default application to open the log files):

```
#PBS -o output.log
#PBS -e error.log
```

Once I got into this I found even more nice things which could be interesting:

Combine output and error log with:

```
$ qsub -o output.log -j oe your.pbs
```

Place the joined output in another location other than the working directory

```
$ qsub -o $HOME/tutorials/logs/output.log -j oe your.pbs
```

Using the *.pbs script created earlier, submit a job that emails you for all conditions:

```
$ qsub -m abe -M NetID@nyu.edu your.pbs
```

*Note*: More and in greater detail can be found [here](https://wikis.nyu.edu/display/NYUHPC/Tutorial+-+Submitting+a+job+using+qsub)